Need to remove multiple suffixes from a lot of files in a Windows environment
Need a PowerShell Script or a way to remove the multiple suffixes to just one suffix.
I have a few hundred files with filename.dat.dat, filename.dat.BAK_YYYYMMDD.BAK_YYYYMMDD or such combinations. Need to have them just as Filename.dat
From the command prompt as Administrator, I tried C:\temp >ren .dat.BAK *.dat. The rename in Windows, renames all the files to one name with hundreds of copies.

If you you are not focused on command-line options only you can use a UI tools like AntRenamer which can be configured pretty quick deleting certain parts of a large set of files.
